# Why Code Analysis is not working on TFS 2012 build?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

As suggested in one of the related questions that you need to install VS 2012 on the TFS 2012 build server to run Code Analysis as a part of build process.

Due to some reason it is still not working nor giving any error.

Build settings for Code Analysis is set to Always but still it does not run.

However, I have open the same project on the TFS build server in VS 2012 and try to run the Code Analysis and it ran successfully.

I need to get it working.

Can anyone please suggest if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

You project configuration will need a Code Analysis Ruleset to run against.

You can set this per configuration in your Project Options:
[image]